# Select case doesn't work as expected

Tags: linux, shell, select, menu, case

I wrote this case select statement which refuses to work and I am unable to figure out what I am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
echo; echo "Did you see a display?"
select YN in "yes" "no" ; do
    case $YN in
        yes)
            echo "$2 at $X x $Y @$REF Hz">>/root/ran.log
            break   
        ;;
        no)
            echo "$2 at $X x $Y @$REF Hz">>/root/didntrun.log
            break   
        ;;
    esac
done
```

This is the bash -x output of this part of the code. #? repeats many times on the screen and skips prompting the user and jumps to the next part of the code.

```
+ echo 'Did you see a display?'
Did you see a display?
+ select yn in '"yes"' '"no"'
1) yes
2) no
#? + case $yn in
#? + case $yn in
#? + case $yn in
#? + case $yn in
#? + case $yn in
#? + case $yn in
#? + case $yn in
#? + case $yn in
#? + case $yn in
#? + case $yn in
#? + case $yn in
#? + case $yn in
#? + case $yn in
#? + case $yn in
#? + case $yn in
#? + case $yn in
#?
```

EDIT: Figured this happens because the select code is being called in between a loop that reads lines from a file. The change in stdin to the file causes select to skip user prompt and tries to read from file. Now I need a way to sort this out.

EDIT 2:
This is the code that makes the calls the fnUseResolution function inside which is the select statement.

res.log has resolution in each line in the format e.g. 1920 1080 60

```
FILE=res.log
BAKIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
exec 3<&0
exec 0<$FILE
while read -r LINE
do
    fnUseResolution $LINE app1
    fnUseResolution $LINE app2
    fnUseResolution $LINE app3
done
exec 0<&3
IFS=$BAKIFS
```

Comment: The title here makes me think of [The Pragmatic Programmer & "select isn't broken"](http://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/tips)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That works fine for me, it stops and lets me enter either `1` or `2`.

See the following transcript:

```
pax$ cat qq.sh
echo "Did you see a display?"
select YN in "yes" "no" ; do
    case $YN in
        yes)
            echo YES
            break   
        ;;
        no)
            echo NO
            break   
        ;;
    esac
done

pax$ ./qq.sh
Did you see a display?
1) yes
2) no
#? 1
YES

pax$ ./qq.sh
Did you see a display?
1) yes
2) no
#? 2
NO

pax$ _
```

Are you sure that the standard input is connected to your terminal at that point?

---

Since you've confirmed my suspicions that your standard input isn't connected to the terminal, there *is* a somewhat tricky way to fix it by fiddling with file handles.

Consider the following code which does what you indicated in your comment (calling a function accepting standard input from within a loop that has redirected standard input):

```
fn() {
    echo "Did you see a display?"
    select YN in "yes" "no" ; do
        case $YN in
            yes)
                echo YES $YN $REPLY
                break
            ;;
            no)
                echo NO $YN $REPLY
                break
            ;;
        esac
    done
}

echo 'A
B
C
D' | while read ; do
    echo $REPLY
    fn
    echo ====
done
```

If you run this code, you'll see:

```
A
Did you see a display?
1) yes
2) no
#? #? #? #? 
=====
```

This indicates that the input was intermixed among the two readers, `while read` and `select`.

The trick to solving this is to disassociate the two readers by changing the code as follows:

```
(echo 'A
B
C
D' | while read ; do
    echo $REPLY
    fn <&4
done) 4<&0
```

The output for this is:

```
A
Did you see a display?
1) yes
2) no
#? 1                         <- my input.
YES yes 1
=====
B
Did you see a display?
1) yes
2) no
#? 2                         <- my input.
NO no 2
=====
C
Did you see a display?
1) yes
2) no
#? 1                         <- my input.
YES yes 1
=====
D
Did you see a display?
1) yes
2) no
#? 2                         <- my input.
NO no 2
=====
```

What this does (in its own hideous fashion) is start a subshell to run your whole thing, with the trick being that the subshell first connects the *current* standard input (terminal, probably) to file handle 4 for later use.

*Inside* the subshell, you run your normal `while read` loop which changes the standard input (file handler 0) to read from the `echo` statement.

But here's the trick: when you call your function, you tell it to take its standard input from file handle 4 rather than the current file handle 0. Since this is connected to the saved, original, standard input, it won't get anything from the `while read` standard input (the output of `echo`).

This may take some time to wrap your head around (and I recall having to pick my brains off the floor the first time I saw this, since my head exploded). But, once you understand how it works, you'll see its elegance :-)

The output for this is:

```
A
Did you see a display?
1) yes
2) no
#? 1
YES yes 1
=====
B
Did you see a display?
1) yes
2) no
#? 2
NO no 2
=====
C
Did you see a display?
1) yes
2) no
#? 1
YES yes 1
=====
D
Did you see a display?
1) yes
2) no
#? 2
NO no 2
=====
```

---

And, based on your code, probably a good starting point is to surround the whole lot to preserve standard input, something like:

```
(FILE=res.log
BAKIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
exec 3<&0
exec 0<$FILE
while read -r LINE
do
    fnUseResolution $LINE app1 <&4
    fnUseResolution $LINE app2 <&4
    fnUseResolution $LINE app3 <&4
done
exec 0<&3
IFS=$BAKIFS) 4<&0
```

I'm assuming here that your function is `fnUseResolution`.

However, in looking at that code, it may be simpler to use a different file handle for the `read` rather than the `select` since you have more control over that than I thought.

Try out:

```
FILE=res.log
BAKIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
#exec 3<&0
exec 4<$FILE
while read -u 4 -r LINE
do
    fnUseResolution $LINE app1
    fnUseResolution $LINE app2
    fnUseResolution $LINE app3
done
#exec 0<&3
IFS=$BAKIFS
```

The `-u 4` option to read tels it to use file handle 4 rather than 0 and I've changed the `exec` to match that. I haven't tested it but it *should* work okay.

By doing it that way, you never change standard input so it should be okay within the function. Additionally, there's no reason to save/restore it in file handle 3 in that case, hence I've commented those `exec` calls out.

Comment: Figured out the reason it isn't working: The select statement is inside a function and this function is called inside a loop which reads input from a file, a line at a time. Since the select falls in between the file read the stdin changes to the file and fails to prompt input from the user. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @fzkl: yes, there is, although it's pretty complex. See the update.

Comment: Hmm.. this is confusing, especially since I am not well versed with file handling. I have updated my original post with the part of the code that handles the read. How would your solution apply? Thanks for the info. I just need to learn it myself.

Answer (score 0):

This should work; Bash return the user response to variable $REPLY.
This shall work, if you type in "yes" or "no".

```
echo; echo "Did you see a display?"
select YN in "yes" "no" ; do
    case $REPLY in
        yes)
            echo "$2 at $X x $Y @$REF Hz">>/root/ran.log
            break   
        ;;
        no)
            echo "$2 at $X x $Y @$REF Hz">>/root/didntrun.log
            break   
        ;;
        *)
            echo "blah! blah! $REPLY"
            break
    esac
done
```

Comment: That won't work, it returns the _entered_ value in `$REPLY` (in other words, `2` rather than `no`). You'll need to adjust the case bits.